# How to customize Highchart graph similar to linkedin "Who's viewed your profile > Viewers found you from LinkedIn.com"

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I would like to customize or create a graph using highcharts similar to linkedin "Who's viewed your profile > Viewers found you from Linked-in.com"

can anyone guide me how to achieve this?![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Similar demo (different series type) http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume, but this chart is customised (because defaulty you cannot set a piece of line serie as dashed).